# If statement comparing strings error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This one is odd - I can't see what is wrong with the code!

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"ENTERING SETTINGS VIEW, SAVED CURRENCY IS: %@", [userDefaults1 stringForKey:@"userCurrency"]);

if ([[userDefaults1 stringForKey:@"userCurrency"] isEqualToString:@"EURO"]){
    NSLog(@"ENTERING THE IF");
         _currency.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
}
```

I am trying to take the value of the NSUserDefault (which hs been previously saved as a string) and create an if statement to set up the view.

The output I from the logs is:

> 2013-11-10 17:17:49.948 APP[3433:70b] ENTERING SETTINGS VIEW, SAVED CURRENCY IS: EURO

and I get a Thread 1  breakpoint error when I try and compile... the `NSLog` suggests that the string is there... any ideas?

Comment: What's the error when the app crashes?

Comment: " Thread 1 breakpoint " didn't you let a breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: you get a "breakpoint error" at compilation time eh? so it errors at compile time and yet you get an evaluated `NSLog`. you aren't speaking sense. sounds like you just run into a mistakenly set breakpoint when you run.